# Copy First Cell of a row based on a criteria

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, copy, find

[image]

I need to copy the Employee Name in Column I until a new Employee Comes up. For example, Copy Brown, Nat till row 8 i.e. Code: Shift 1, then start copying Brown, Rob. I used If with find function but i cant make it work.

Comment: Please share the code that didn't work, so it can easily be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is mighty short on detail but the function below should help you get one step nearer to what you need. Please try it.

```
Private Function EmployeeData(ByVal FirstRow As Long) As Variant
    ' 233

    Dim Arr     As Variant
    Dim Cl      As Long                 ' last used column
    Dim R       As Long                 ' lop counter: rows

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Arr = .Range(.Cells(1, "I"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp)).Value
        R = FirstRow
        Do
            If InStr(1, Arr(R + 1, 1), "Employee Name:", vbTextCompare) = 1 Then Exit Do
            R = R + 1
        Loop While R < UBound(Arr)
        
        With .UsedRange
            Cl = .Columns.Count + .Column - 1
        End With
        EmployeeData = .Range(.Cells(FirstRow, "A"), .Cells(R, Cl)).Value
    End With
End Function
```

The function takes one argument. That is the number of the row where the employee's name is first found. Starting from that row, the function searches until the next name is found in column I and returns the data from the rows in between. It returns all data, from column A to the last used column.

Use the procedure below to test. Observe that `EmployeeData(14)` specifies row 14 as the first row of a block and that the loop that follows just prints column I:I although the array contains all the columns.

```
Sub GetData()
    ' 233
    
    Dim Arr     As Variant
    Dim R       As Long
    
    Arr = EmployeeData(14)
    For R = 1 To UBound(Arr)
        Debug.Print Arr(R, 9)
    Next R
End Sub
```

In real life, you will probably need to search for the first row before you can run this code. That search, if needed, is easy to integrate into the test procedure.